# Convert string data to numerical data

Tags: python

I am working on **"Classifying income data using Support Vector Machines"** model and code below is to **convert** **string** data to **numerical** data.

**Code:**

```
label_encoder =[]
X_encoded = np.empty(X.shape)
for i, item in enumerate(X[0]):
    if item.isdigit():
        X_encoded[:,i] = X[:,i]
    else:
        label_encoder.append(preprocessing.LabelEncoder())
        X_encoded[:,i] = label_encoder[-1].fit_transform(X[:,i])
X = X_encoded[:, :-1].astype(int) 
y = X_encoded[:, -1].astype(int)
```

**Erorr:**

```
<ipython-input-27-6393acaab006> in <module>()
      2 label_encoder =[]
      3 X_encoded = np.empty(X.shape)
----> 4 for i, item in enumerate(X[0]):
      5     if item.isdigit():
      6         X_encoded[:,i] = X[:,i]

**IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with** size 0
```

Comment: `X` must be empty, so there's no `X[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

If your dataset includes categorical data then encode your data using LabelEncoder class

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder 
labelEncoder_X = LabelEncoder()
X[row,column] = labelEncoder_X.fit_transform(X[row,column])
```

It will convert your string data of a particular column to numerical data starting from 0